# I need a regex pattern which matches digit followed by dot max of 5 times without spaces

Tags: java, regex

I have a requirement for an ID number validation which requires digits followed by dot , same which can be repeated max 5 times. e.g 123.3.4.31.5 ,23.45.65.23,123.3.1 all are valid but 1.1.234.3.50.6 ,12.34. is invalid

I expect a 1 to 3 digit number followed by a dot once, and another 1 to 3 digit number which can again be followed by one dot and digit , and this sequence can repeat a max of 5 times , with no spaces and dot should not be at the end. And dot can be present a max of 4 times with digits preceding and succeeding 1 dot. e.g 123.123.123.2.3

I have already checked for IP address validations but its not that much flexible

```java
Pattern idCardNumberPattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+(\\.\\d+)*");
if (idCardNumberPattern.matcher("9.9.9.9.9").matches()) {
    System.out.println("true");
}
```

I tried this but this repeats the digits dot sequence any number of times but expected is  1 to  max of 5 times

Comment: Why is `1.1.2.3.5` invalid?

Comment: Why is 123.34.3.1.5 valid and  1.1.2.3.5 invalid? Please make your question clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex you're looking for is

```
^(\\d{1,3}\\.){0,4}\\d{1,3}$
```

> Explaination: You expect a 1 to 3 digit number followed by a dot 0 or
>   4 times, and another 1 to 3 digit number in the end.

You can use https://regexr.com/ to test and create new patterns.

By the way, you can print the result of the 'matches()' method instead of putting an extra if condition, e.g:

```
System.out.println(idCardNumberPattern.matcher("9.9.9.9.9").matches());
```

Comment: I think you should escape the dot. Otherwise 9x9s9a9s9 matches too.

Comment: Yes I expect a 1 to 3 digit number followed by a dot , and another 1 to 3 digit number which can again be followed by a dot and digit , and this sequence can repeat a max of 5 times , with no spaces and dot shouldnt be at the end.e.g 123.123.123.2.3

Comment: Ok then this should work for you. It was actually the explanation of the regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(\d+\.){4}(\d+)$
```

digit and following dots four times and one digit at the end.
^ and $ is for exact match.

Comment: I expect a 1 to 3 digit number followed by a dot once, and another 1 to 3 digit number which can again be followed by one dot and digit , and this sequence can repeat a max of 5 times , with no spaces and dot shouldnt be at the end. And dot can be present a max of 4 times with digits preceding and succeding 1 dot. e.g 123.123.123.2.3